# rmagick won't find imagemagick on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick

I'm deploying a railsapp to ubuntu

rmagick is installed via "bundle install vendor".  it installs , and the app runs -- but this error gets thrown :

```
uninitialized constant Image::Magick
```

when trying to read:

```
source_image = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/public/system/assets/#{self.id}/original/#{self.asset_file_name}").first
```

I've done the following:

- uninstsalled, then reinstalled, ImageMagick on the server
- uninstalled, then reinstalled, rmagick on the server
- uninstalled, then reinstalled, rmagick via bundler
- run with only the bundler rmagick installed
- run with the bundler and system rmagick installed
- proxied nginx to rails-server to ensure the error is not related to passenger

I'm going a bit crazy trying to figure out what else I can do to make rmagick see imagemagick

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace from this error please?

Comment: Thanks for asking Ryan.  It turned out that the person who originally deployed the app didn't configure it in the Gemfile as it prefers/needs to function in many environments.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After hours of fighting and recompiling imagemagick and rmagick under different combinations, I lucked out on a 1 line fix

Gemfile

```
- gem 'rmagick'
+ gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

Bundler requires the gem name by default,

i.e. `:require => 'rmagick'`.

But the file being included is actually 'RMagick.rb'. For case-insensitive file systems, like OS X, this will work, but for **case-sensitive** file systems, like Ubuntu, the file will not be found.

This can be one of the reasons why the error can't be produced on the dev system, even when running in production mode.

Comment: Found this helpful little tip on Thanksgiving day.  THANK YOU.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks for the explanation. The case-insensitivity of OSX is driving me nuts at times..

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `gem install rmagick` as a privileged user fixed the issue for me.

Not really a helpful solution, but I guess in my case I didn't actually have RMagick installed properly, even though bundler thought I did.